# Read access violation current was 0xCDCDCDCD, Linked List Windows

Tags: c++

Error in debug: Read access violation current was 0xCDCDCDCD

Please help me

This is the struct

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
} node_t;
```

This is the function for add new data

```
node_t* push(node_t* head, int data)
{
    node_t* current = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    current->data = data;
    current->next = head;
    head = current;

    return current;
}
```

This function print all data of the list

```
void print_list(node_t* head)
{
    node_t* current = head;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf("Data: %d\n", current->data); // READ ACCESS VIOLATION
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Main of program

```
int main()
{
    node_t* head = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    head = push(head, 1);
    head = push(head, 2);
    print_list(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read this: [In Visual Studio C++, what are the memory allocation representations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations) And consider what `head->next` points to after your *original* allocation in `main()` (that allocation shouldn't even be there; it should be initially `NULL`). Unrelated question, what archaic book are you using that suggests managing memory in C++ with `malloc` and `free` in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

You never initialize the contents of `head` in main before first use. 0xCDCDCDCD is uninitialized memory, at least under Microsoft compilers and building with _DEBUG defined.  So `head->next` and `head->data` will be 0xCDCDCDCD in debug mode, and undefined data in a release build.

Instead of initializing `head` with an uninitialized instance of a node, just use:

```
node_t* head = NULL;
```